# Distance preserving function on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, and $B(H)$ the set of all bounded linear operators on $H$. It is known that an isometry in $B(H)$ is distance preserving. I am trying to show the converse:

> Every distance preserving function $f : H \to H$ has the form $f(x) = f(0) +Tx, \forall x \in H$ for some isometry $T \in B(H)$.

Comment: check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817382/is-a-similarity-map-necessarily-affine-linear/817437#817437 there it is shown that a similarity map (isometry up to multiplicative constant) is affine. The proof works for finite dimensional vector spaces. The generalization to infinite dimensional is that an isometry is of the form $f(x)=f(0)+T(x)$ where T is linear form $H$ to the (closure of the) image of $f$ (which can be a proper subspace of $H$ in dimension infinite)

Comment: This result is known as the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)

Comment: This is not true without an assumption that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f : H \to H$ is distance preserving.

Define $T : H \to H$ as $$Tx = f(x) - f(0), \quad\forall x\in X$$ We obviously have $T0 = 0$.

$T$ is distance preserving:

$$\|Tx - Ty\| = \|(Tx - f(0)) - (Ty - f(0))\| = \|f(x) - f(y)\| = \|x - y\|, \quad\forall x, y \in H$$

Since $T0 = 0$, $T$ also preserves the norm.

$$\|Tx\| = \|Tx - T0\| = \|x - 0\| = \|x\|, \quad\forall x \in H$$

Furthermore, $T$ preserves the inner product:

\begin{align}
0 &= \|Tx - Ty\|^2 - \|x-  y\|^2 \\
&= \langle Tx - Ty, Tx - Ty\rangle - \langle x  -y, x-y\rangle\\
&= \|Tx\|^2 - 2\langle Tx, Ty\rangle + \|Ty\|^2 - \|x\|^2 + 2\langle x, y\rangle - \|y\|^2  \\
&= 2(\langle Tx, Ty\rangle - \langle x, y\rangle)
\end{align}

which implies $\langle Tx, Ty\rangle = \langle x, y\rangle, \forall x,y \in H$.

Now we can show that $T$ is also linear:

$$ \|\alpha x + \beta y - z\|^2 = \|\alpha x\|^2 + \|\beta y\|^2 + \|z\|^2 - 2\langle \alpha x, z\rangle - 2 \langle \beta y, z\rangle + 2 \langle \alpha x, \beta y\rangle$$
$$ \|\alpha Tx + \beta Ty - Tz\|^2 = |\alpha|^2\|Tx\|^2 + |\beta|^2\|Ty\|^2 + \|Tz\|^2 - 2\alpha\langle Tx, Tz\rangle - 2 \beta\langle Ty, Tz\rangle + 2  \alpha\beta\langle Tx, Ty\rangle$$

Right hand sides are equal so

$$\|\alpha x + \beta y - z\| = \|\alpha Tx + \beta Ty - Tz\|, \quad\forall x,y,z \in H, \forall \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$$

In particular, for $z = \alpha x + \beta y$ we get

$$0 = \|\alpha x + \beta y - z\| = \|\alpha Tx + \beta Ty - T(\alpha x + \beta y)\|$$

which implies $T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha Tx + \beta Ty, \forall x, y \in H, \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Therefore, $T \in B(H)$ is a linear isometry and $f(x) = f(0) + Tx$, $\forall x\in H$.

---

Note:

Norm-preserving maps $U \in B(H)$ are usually also required to be *surjective* to be called isometries. In that case, $U$ is called a [unitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator) and a common equivalent definition is

$$U^*U = UU^* = I$$

Your distance preserving function $f$ has to be surjective in order for $T$ above to be unitary. Namely, $\|Tx\| = \|x\|, \forall x \in X$ implies that $T$ is injective, and also $T$ is surjective since $f$ is.

Otherwise, consider $f : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined as $$(x_1, x_2, \ldots ) \mapsto (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$$
which is distance-preserving but $T = f$ is not surjective and hence not unitary.

Comment: The original question didn't required $H$ to be real. This condition is added by your edit. What about the complex case?

Comment: @mma The claim is false for complex Hilbert spaces, e.g. complex conjugation $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ preserves distances but is not isometric.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a mistyping. Isometries are distance preserving functions by definition. I think you wanted to write that Complex conjugation isn't *linear*.

Comment: @mma Ah yes, for me an isometry of $H$ is by default an element of $B(H)$.

Comment: Perhaps linear and antilinear isometries together are the distance and origin preserving transformations in the complex case (see [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482576/mazur-ulam-like-theorem-for-complex-hilbert-spaces) about this).